# Converting Fixnum to word in Ruby

Tags: ruby

For some reason my code is displaying nothing. It should display `'one'`. Any ideas as to why it's not?

```
## write function that takes a number
## check length of number
## if length is one
## conditional statements for each ones digit

def nums_to_words(num)
    length = num.to_s.length
    string = length.to_s

    if string.length < 2
        elsif string[0] == '1'
            puts 'one'
        elsif string[0] == '2'
            puts 'two'
        elsif string[0] == '3'
            puts 'three'
        elsif string[0] == '4'
            puts 'four'
        elsif string[0] == '5'
            puts 'five'
        elsif string[0] == '6'
            puts 'six'
        elsif string[0] == '7'
            puts 'seven'
        elsif string[0] == '8'
            puts 'eight'
        elsif string[0] == '9'
            puts 'nine'
    end
end


nums_to_words(1)
```

Comment: No, it should not display anything.

Comment: I think you know what I meant, @Alexey :p

Comment: I mean that what you said was not true.

Comment: "Computer does not do what the user wants, it does what the user tells it to do" :).

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
NUMBERS = [ 'zero', 'one' 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eigth', 'nine' ]
def nums_to_words(num)
  str = num.to_s
  if str.size == 1
    puts NUMBERS[str.to_i]
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this method! Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to implement this and it seems there's a step missing. How is the NUMBERS constant linked to the function at all?

Comment: @DylanRichards: You are right, I forgot to upcase the constants in the method. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct answer:

```
def nums_to_words(num)
    length = num.to_s.length
    num = num.to_s

    if num.length < 2
        if num[0] == '1'
            puts 'one'
        elsif num[0] == '2'
            puts 'two'
        elsif num[0] == '3'
            puts 'three'
        elsif num[0] == '4'
            puts 'four'
        elsif num[0] == '5'
            puts 'five'
        elsif num[0] == '6'
            puts 'six'
        elsif num[0] == '7'
            puts 'seven'
        elsif num[0] == '8'
            puts 'eight'
        elsif num[0] == '9'
            puts 'nine'
        end
    end
end


nums_to_words(3)
```